# Why if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty )$ then $\frac{|f(x)|}{x}$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose that $f : [1, ∞) → \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1, ∞)$ .

Prove that there
exists $M > 0$ such that $$\frac{|f(x)|}{x}<M \; \; \; \; \forall  x\geq 1$$

First, I noticed that $f,x$ both continuous on $[1, ∞)$ and $x\neq 0$ on $[1, ∞)$, so $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is continuous on $[1, ∞)$.

Then, $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t "$\forall x$ that satisfies $|x-x_{0}|<\delta $ we have $\left | \frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(x_{0})}{x_{0}} \right |< \varepsilon $."

This implies, $\left | \left |\frac{f(x)}{x}  \right |-\left |\frac{f(x_{0})}{x_{0}}  \right | \right |= \left |\frac{|f(x)|}{x}-\frac{|f(x_{0})|}{x_{0}}  \right |< \varepsilon $

So, $\frac{|f(x)|}{x}<\frac{|f(x_{0})|}{x_{0}}+\varepsilon \leq |f(x_{0})|+\varepsilon $

But, I'm stuck here because it doesn't seem the right way to get the $M$.

Can I get some enlightenment for this problem? (What to note, and where to start)

Comment: Your proof is not going to work because you're using uniform continuity of $f(x)/x$ instead of $f(x)$.  Uniform continuity of $f$ itself is more powerful.

Comment: Intuition:  if $x$ is time and $f(x)$ is position on a 1D track, uniform continuity for $\epsilon = 1$ is the same as saying that there is a period of time $\delta$ seconds so that for in any window of $\delta$ seconds we cannot move more than $1$ meter.  In other words, you can never go faster than $1m / \delta$.  So you can't go any further than $1 m /\delta$ x over a span of $x$ seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and Partition $[1,\infty)$ into a countable union of open intervals $U_i$ of width $\delta$ such that for any $x,y\in U_i$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Thus by triangle inequality

$$|f(x)-f(1)|= |f(x)-f(x-\epsilon)+f(x-\epsilon)-f(x-2\epsilon)+...-f(1)|\leq \frac{x}{\epsilon}\epsilon=x.$$

The result follows after rearranging the above and using the fact that $x\geq 1$.

Comment: I'm pretty new to the concept of "countable". So, I want to make it sure if I'm understanding it right. We can devide $[1,\infty )$ into a union of open sets because we can have $(1,2),(2,3),...\cup \left \{1,2,3,...  \right \}$?

Comment: And why do we get $\frac{x}{\epsilon}$?

Comment: You don't strictly need the first part, it's just an abstract way of saying what comes next: we're leapfrogging from $x$ to $1$ in steps of width epsilon (except possibly for the last one).

Comment: There are at most $x/\epsilon$ steps between $x$ and $1$ of size $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for uniformly continuous funcitons, one has $|f(x)|\leq Ax+B$ for $A,B>0$ and sufficiently large $x>0$, and so $|f(x)|/x$ is bounded.

Look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468669/bound-a-uniformly-continuous-functions-image-by-a-linear-function).